# MacBook Pro (2018) Overheating issues (Latest Mojave)

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, hardware, temperature, mojave

I recently bought the Macbook Pro (2018) base model with the following specs -

- 2.2 Ghz 6 core i7
- 16 GB RAM
- 256 GB SSD
- Radeon Pro 555X 4096 MB
- Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- Mojave but this problem existed even in latest High Sierra

It overheats. The exact temperatures of each location are given here [[image: Temperatures]
but the laptop is generally uncomfortably hot to touch.

1. Does anyone else here have the same problem?
2. How do I go about diagnosing this? Here is a screenshot of running processes.[[image]

Comment: I do not see any overheating ? could you point me to it

Comment: Neither screen shot shows an overheating condition.  How are you determining that it is?

Comment: It just ocurred to me from @Buscar웃's comment that the outer temps are near body temperature. However, the laptop is uncomfortably hot to touch compared to a Macbook pro (2015) which I had used as a daily driver previously. Is it possible that the temperature readings are glitchy?

Comment: As noted tere seems to be no overheating. The fans are running so you are using the computr heavily. What is the python app you are running?

Answer (score 1):

Your average body temp is 37.2 Celsius !

I do not see any surface area on your Laptop that is higher than 38 C, so you would not feel it as hot.

As for the diverse electronic devices and Integrated circuits (CPU), they are designed to withstand up to 110 Celsius.

Your Mac will turn off at 105 C.

None of your results come even close to been HOT.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Now that you mention it, the readings logically indicate that the laptop is not overheating. However, compared to a 2015 model I had owned, the laptop is uncomfortably hot to touch. Is it possible that temperature sensors glitchy? How do I diagnose this?

Comment: what app did you use to get the readings, how is that app calibrated to convert analog signal (sensor) to digital signal. You can always bring it back to the store since you just bough it and have them look at it.

Comment: I used the app called [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

Of course, I reserved that for a last resort.

Comment: Have you tried Temperature Guage from Tunabelly software? Reports temperatures at different locations inside you mac. Also has fan control.  https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/tgupdate/